# urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Forwarding failure

Tags: urllib2

OS: ubuntu14.04LTS python2.7

http_proxy="127.0.0.1:8118"
use Privoxy socket to http

when i use urllib2 open url

urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 503 Forwarding failure

what is error?